# CSS background-color pulse animation for unknow background color

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a list of divs with a background color determined by a `knockout.js` observable. The background color of the first div should pulse slightly to make clear, that this is the active element. I created a pulse animation with css and keyframes, but this seems to only work with a fixed color known at "compile time". Can I somehow make that more dynamic? I already tried to use the `inherit` keyword, but that doesn't work

```
<div class="cch-current-storage" data-bind="style: { 'background-color': storageType.color }">Bla</div>
<div data-bind="style: { 'background-color': storageType.color }">Next</div>

<style>
.cch-current-storage {
      animation-name: color;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
      animation-timing-function:ease
}

@@keyframes color {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: inherit;}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all there is a typo... css-current-storage vs .ccs-current-storage

I made fiddle you can look here (https://jsfiddle.net/z9modqt4/)

css

```
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.css-current-storage {
      animation-name: color;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
      animation-timing-function: ease;
}


@keyframes color {
  to {
    background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

html

```
<div class="css-current-storage" style='background-color: yellow' >Bla</div>
```

it seems to work if I left empty space in `from` (**delete `from` completly**)

Its counter intuitive because that way it works from `to` to `from`. So it works in other direction (because of `animation-direction: alternate-reverse` like Temani said in comment)

Comment: you need to remove the *from* completely. When either *from* or *to* are not specified the browser will automatically used the computed value of the element, in this case it's the yellow background. It's not counter intuitive since you defined `animation-direction: alternate-reverse;`

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm! Are there any neat tricks to only modify the luminance or saturation of the existing background color, without knowing it ecactly? I want to make if flash, no matter which color it's set to.

Comment: There is 'background-blend-mode'.

Comment: @sonic Thank you, but that doesn't help, because you can't stack multiple `background-color`s on top of each other.